# Can't save mp4 video after sending eos to pipeline

Tags: python, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I have tried many different things but I am not able to send and eos message when ctrl+c is pressed and properly stop my pipeline and obtain a video file. Whay am I missing here?

```py
def bus_call(bus, message, loop):
    t = message.type
    if t == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        logger.info("End-of-stream\n")
        loop.quit()
    elif t==Gst.MessageType.WARNING:
        err, debug = message.parse_warning()
        logger.info("Warning: %s: %s\n" % (err, debug))
    elif t == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        err, debug = message.parse_error()
        logger.info("Error: %s: %s\n" % (err, debug))
        loop.quit()
    return True

# Set up pipeline
logger.info("GStreamer initialization")
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

logger.info("Creating Pipeline")
pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

# create and add elements
....

loop = GObject.MainLoop()
bus = pipeline.get_bus()
bus.add_signal_watch()
bus.connect("message", bus_call, loop)

logger.info("Starting pipeline")
self.gst_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

try:
    loop.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

Comment: You send EOS and immediately stop the pipeline. There is no time for the EOS to go through the pipeline.

Comment: Yes but how should I handle that? I mean I want to finish when eos has gone throught but I don't know how

Comment: Stop the main loop.. or use locks and signals..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. Answer was in this thread https://github.com/beetbox/audioread/issues/63.

So basically I updated my pygobject version to 3.38.0 and used the new constructor `GObject.MainLoop.new(None, False)` to avoid the default sigint problem.

After that I replaced the KeyboardInterrupt exception with a signal handler:

```
signal.signal(
                signal.SIGINT,
                lambda n, f: self.gst_pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos()),
            )
    
    loop = GObject.MainLoop()
    bus = pipeline.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.connect("message", bus_call, loop)
    
    logger.info("Starting pipeline")
    self.gst_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    
    loop.run()


pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

And this worked like a charm!